# using short-circuit operators to throw error - javascript

Tags: javascript

I know that jslint/jshint don't like it but I wanted to know if there were any real issues with doing something like.

```
var err = function(msg) { throw new Error(msg); };
```

**Example 1:** Assignment

```
var foo = bar.foo || baz.foo || err('missing foo property');
```

**Example 2:** Validation

```
typeof foo['bar'] !== 'string' && err('bar has to be a string');
```

Are there any gotcha's that I should be aware of?

Comment: Example 1 certainly looks dangerous since if `bar.foo` or `baz.foo` exist but are not truthy then it will very quickly get very muddy

Comment: @MattWhipple Good point! So maybe it should be `var foo = "foo" in bar || "foo" in baz || err('missing foo property');` ?

Comment: @Ian It's probably best avoided if it can't be done cleanly (once the point where the short cut isn't quite so short).  Your solution is beginning the descent towards obfuscatory idioms.

Comment: @iliacholy If you like that solution then you likely should not be considered with what jslint tells you at all

Comment: @MattWhipple So what do you mean? Instead of using this short circuiting, just make it more organized with `if / else`?

Comment: wait no, `in` returns a bool. So the assignment wouldn't even work.

Comment: @Ian I'm saying if you want to use short circuiting then use it when it makes sense and is readable, but don't jam things in when it doesn't.  In the case of example A a (tabular) ternary would likely be a better option for terse code.

Comment: Oh wow, completely missed the point. I understand what you're trying to do. I think that since I kept seeing `||`, I kept thinking this is like an `if` statement (which I know is definitely not). So nevermind :)

Comment: @MattWhipple I see, I see, and I agree about using a ternary. If you wanted to use short circuit, wouldn't it actually be `var foo = ("foo" in bar && bar.foo) || ("foo" in baz && baz.foo) || err('missing foo property');` ? I just like trying to figure these things out anyways...

Comment: @Ian if you're trying to get the value of `bar.foo` or `baz.foo` into `foo` then I don't think you can include type checking.

Comment: nvm, you're totally right! cool!

Comment: What do you mean type checking in this case? Just wondering

Comment: @Ian that still wouldn't address the truthiness issue

Comment: @MattWhipple Damnit, why can't I think straight?

Comment: @Ian exactly why you (or anyone) should avoid this type of coding

Comment: ugh ... `var foo = (toString.call(bar.foo) === '[object String]' && bar.foo) || err('invalid foo')`

Comment: @iliacholy Haha but as MattWhipple pointed out, if `bar.foo` ends up returning a falsey value like `false` or `0`, etc., then it will run the `err` function.

Comment: @MattWhipple You might want to post an answer explaining the falsey problem - it really is a "Gotcha" as the OP is asking about

Comment: true... @MattWhipple I'll accept it as the correct answer if you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As covered in the comments there is a strong chance of unexpected behavior due to JavaScript's loose interpretation of truthiness which is the driving force of the mentioned logical operators.  As such there is a limited subset of conditionals in which the short circuit approach will be useful, and it therefore does not offer a consistent solution.

Out of the 2 examples given example 2 is a good application as it is a readable application of a test with very defined output.  Example 1 however will cause issues if any of the attempted values evaluate to anything which may be valid in the program logic, but `false` from the perspective of the language.  Applying a solution to these types of problems would effectively cancel out any benefit that the syntax could offer.  Solutions for variations on these types of issues may not be consistent, and therefore this introduces a higher risk of bugs introduced at initial creation or any subsequent modifications.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't even recognize the truthiness problem in the first place. Good eye!

Comment: It occurs to me now (now that I've been thinking about it) that the big drawback with the short circuit approach is that it involves depending on the entire expression.  A little ironic given the name...although the name only applies to the particular operation.  There's no option to _return_ at a particular point, which would be due to the difference between an expression and a control structure.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm aware, this is no more wrong than `or die()` in PHP. The short-circuit-ness of the operator is clearly-defined, so the error will only be thrown if the last case is reached.

Answer (score 1):

One of important things to consider is the precedence and interaction with some other operators. Incorrectly placed `,` or brackets can change flow in subtle and not-so-easily readable way. Otherwise it should be safe as long as you ensured that you intended logic matches shortcut rules. And of course, usual gotchas to what language consider truthly apply as well.

Comment: can you elaborate? Examples are always appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are particularly checking if the type is `string`, you are missing a big point. The raw type string has no methods.

```
var s = 'something';
console.log(typeof s);// outputs string

var s = new String('something');// same text as above
console.log(typeof s);//outputs object
```

JavaScript has a feature called auto-boxing. when you invoke string methods on variables declared in the first way, it will automatically switch from string to object string so the proper way to check for a string is:

```
isString = function (obj) { return toString.call(obj) === '[object String]';};
```

Triple equal(===) is used to quickly avoid undefined/null cases and common comparison pitfalls.

Other than that, you are fine. In production, you should also log your errors accordingly and use try catch blocks when you invoke throw functions.

Comment: in your second code block, if `s` is something without a `prototype` then you'll get a `TypeError` trying to access `toString`

Comment: And if `.prototype.toString.call` is the method that always works, why bother with `typeof`?

Comment: No problem, just wanted to talk it out. Also, wouldn't you want to use `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)` instead of just `toString.call(obj)` ?

Comment: @Ian what's the case where just `toString.call` wouldn't work?

Comment: I didn't know `toString` was available like that. What does it refer to? `Function.prototype.toString` ?

Answer (score 1):

Short circuiting the way you've shown in the question should be absolutely fine and imo preferred over elaborate if-else statements (of course the main condition you are checking should be correct in the first place, but that's not the topic here). In addition to more elegant looking code, you are essentially shaving bytes off of the total data the client has to download which is *always* good.